# jQuery plugin for HTML table manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, wysiwyg

I'm searching for a jQuery plugin able to add the controls to manipulate the structure of a given HTML table.

I need to give the user the ability to, for example, add rows and columns, graphically resize them, manage the colspan and rowspan, and so on.

Anyone know some nice plugin to do that? (better if jQuery)

Comment: also,do you want other functionality like sorting, filtering etc.?

Comment: No, I just need something to manage the layout of the table, without data mapping, etc... just for drawing

Comment: it will be better if you will write your own plugin for these requirements,as much i know some of plugins have theses things like adding row,manage the colspan and rowspan etc. but they have also another functionality, that makes these plugin heavier not suitable for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of plugins out there for this, with varying degrees of complexity and function. Probably you should start by looking at [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

Comment: What does jqgrid offer, what doesn't it achieve, **why** is it better?